# Error at the time of testing system using htk

Tags: mfcc, htk

I have trained the system, but at the time of testing the system I am getting the following error:-

**ERROR [+6310]  OpenParmChannel: cannot open Parm File Path/T_TUPT_M0002_PN_10012_1.mfc

ERROR [+6313]  OpenAsChannel: OpenParmChannel failed

ERROR [+6316]  OpenBuffer: OpenAsChannel failed

ERROR [+3250]  ProcessFile: Config parameters invalid

```
    FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite**
```

How this error can be removed?

Comment: I have already created all the mfcc files of the wav files to be tested.

Comment: I deleted one wrong tag, you should add some more.

Comment: Can you add the actual command (with options) that produced this error?

Comment: HVite -T 1 -D -A -H ./work_all_3_train_read_test_oct_2012$exp_name/hmm$i/macros -H ./work_all_3_train_read_test_oct_2012$exp_name/hmm$i/hmmdefs -S ./test.list -C ./analysis_train.conf -I ./test.mlf -i ./work_all_3_train_read_test_oct_2012$exp_name/hmm$i/recout_test.mlf -o SWT -w ./wdnet.txt -p -10.0 -s 0 ./dict.txt ./hmmlist.txt

Comment: where, $exp=5 in the above command

Comment: I got the error. Thanks for your concern...